# In Obj-c putting object back to Nill?

Tags: objective-c

I'm using this to see if I have started using an object or not..

```
if(!sharedInstance.market)
```

But when I am done with the object, it's been removed from the display, I want to set sharedInstance.market back to Nill, so I can set it up again when I need to, but this causes an error in XCode

```
sharedInstance.market = Nill;
```

How do I set it back to Nill? or am I thinking about this wrong?

*Edit*

It's giving me 2 errors and a warning..

> /Classes/Game.m:241:29: Use of undeclared identifier 'Nill'; did you
>   mean 'kill'?
>
> /Classes/Game.m:241:29: Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C
>   pointer type 'int (*)(pid_t, int)' to 'SKMarket *' is disallowed with
>   ARC
>
> /Classes/Game.m:241:27: Incompatible pointer types assigning to
>   'SKMarket *' from 'int (pid_t, int)'

Comment: What error does it cause? Its proper to set unused objects to nil and Xcode shouldn't be throwing errors.

Comment: Do you mean `nil` rather than `Nill`? Otherwise that's probably the error.

Comment: Gives me the same for nill, I've just amended my question with more info.

Comment: `nil` with one lowercase L character

Comment: Ha...it's always the smallest things, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean to do:

```
sharedInstance.market = nil;
```